# Easiest turn-base games you can think of?

Tags: game-design

I'm planning to get into the process of programming multiplayer turn-base games. I would like to start off by making some of the simplest (yet fun) multiplayer turn-base games out there. What are some that you can provide? For example:

- Tic-Tac-Toe
- Rock-Paper-Scissors
- Checkers

Some not so easy games:

- 4 in a row
- chess
- poker

In terms of "ease" of implementation I'm mainly looking at logic. For example, Rock-Paper-Scissors has very simple logic, while chess has logic that is more complicated.

So far I have the following:

- Hexagon
- Heroes of Might and Magic
- Nine Men's Morris
- Connect 4
- 21 (card game)
- Pen the Pig (The Dot game)
- Memory Match

Comment: My first multiplayer game was a Tic-Tac-Toe, and I learned a lot from it. It's pretty simple logic, so you would pay more attention to the networking.

Comment: Rock Paper Scissors isn't *really* turn-based, though.  Both actions are supposed to be done at the same time.

Comment: @tetrad. No wonder my older brother always let me go first! :p

Comment: @Joe your comment made my morning :). Actually I imported my account from SO just to post this

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about polling for game ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Board games are easy to implement, also there is a very old turn based DOS game named [Hexagon](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_E10ydLaLE8), which can be fun to make, add new features and stuff. But the board/table games are fun too. (other random ideas: minesweeper, heroes of m&m, )

Answer (score 2):

Othello/Reversi comes to mind. Should be a piece of cake to code.

Comment: Coding the rules for this one is easy. Doing the AI well is *very* hard.

Comment: @Kramii - There was no mention of AI, was there? That would be the most significant aspect, if it were required. For some reason I thought the OP wanted to network two humans together. (Actually, plugging in an AI 'bot' into a network architecture is a good way to go).

Comment: @Kramii, depends what you mean by "well". Give the squares different weights (corner is worth 20, square next to corner is worth 10, edge is worth 5, square next to edge 2, anything else 1) and use alpha-beta with a lookahead of 2 or 3 moves and random tie-breaking. It won't win tournaments, but it's challenging enough for a casual player.

Comment: @JustJeff: You're quite right: re-reading the question there is no explicit requirement for AI. I was wrong to assume.

Answer (score 1):

Connect 4, 21 (cards), [Pen the Pig](http://www.rinkworks.com/games/pig.cgi?t=1&d=3&newgame=), Memory match

Comment: Is memory match when you just flip two cards and try to remember things underneath.

Comment: @Edgar yes it is

Answer (score 1):

Nine Men's Morris, damn I loved that game as a kid, had one of those little pocket-sized magnetic boards (yeah I was *that* kid...)

Answer (score 1):

[Nim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim) is probably the simplest multiplayer turn-based game. It is simple enough that a designer hacked "playing" it into static dialog trees in *Shin Megami Tensei: Strange Journey*.

Answer (score 1):

The [punch in the face game](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6K89xPZO8ds) would be the simplest and easiest form of turn base game to me.

Comment: I CAREFULLY disagree, just in case you HAVE found a way of punching someone through a computer monitor. :D

Answer (score 1):

An easy old turnbased dos game called Galactic.exe (not galactic conquest) -- pick the number of planets and you randomly get attach ships and defense percentage... simple